# Import CSV file from Google Cloud Storage to Google Cloud SQL

Tags: csv, import, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-sql

I am trying to import a csv file directly into Google Cloud SQL using the command below.

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE "gs:/zuds/stg/ems/product_offering_fact/000002_0" INTO TABLE buydoc CHARACTER SET "utf8" FIELDS TERMINATED BY "^";
```

For some reason, it is returning an error like below. I have confirmed that the file exists. However, notice that the path in the error string has only one '/'
Is this a bug or am I missing something obvious?

```
ERROR 2 (HY000) at line 1: File 'gs:/zuds/stg/ems/product_offering_fact/000002_0' not found (Errcode: 2)
```

Note:If I use the UI described in the link below, it works. However, the UI does not support non-comma delimited files.
https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/import-export

Comment: What does App Engine have to do with this...?  Isn't it an extraneous tag here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cloud SQL doesn't support running LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE with "gs://" path. From the UI, as the doc suggests, only comma delimited files are supported at this point. Here are two workarounds:

1. Transform your file to CSV and do an import through UI
2. Download your gs:// file to your local disk and then run LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE pointing to the path on your local disk.

Comment: Thanks Tianzhou. As you also mentioned, gs:// was not recognized as "local". I pulled the file to local (on one of the cloud machines) and used the same command to push it to mySQL database.

Answer (score 2):

> **Unsupported MySQL statements**: Sending any of the following types of
>   SQL statements will generate an error with the message "Error 1290:
>   The MySQL server is running with the google option so it cannot
>   execute this statement"
>
> LOAD DATA INFILE Note: LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE is supported. SELECT ...
>   INTO OUTFILE SELECT ... INTO DUMPFILE INSTALL PLUGIN ... UNINSTALL
>   PLUGIN CREATE FUNCTION ... SONAME ...

https://cloud.google.com/sql/faq#supportmysqlfeatures

Additionally, the mysql command line will not understand a gs:// file reference.