# Import CSV file from Local to Google Cloud SQL

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-sql

Following the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/import-export/#csv_file_reqs), I am trying to import a local CSV onto a MySQL db hosted on GCP. I am using the following console command:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE "C:/Users/user1/gcp/Feb_Pull.csv" INTO TABLE actuals CHARACTER SET 'utf8mb4' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"' ESCAPED BY '\"';
```

I get a 'File not found' error. Notes:

- I'm using a Windows machine
- I've also tried the code below but that does not work as noted in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28975978/import-csv-file-from-google-cloud-storage-to-google-cloud-sql).

> ```
> > LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE
> > "gs://[projectname].appspot.com/bucket/Feb_Pull.csv" INTO TABLE
> > actuals CHARACTER SET 'utf8mb4' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY
> > ENCLOSED BY '\"' ESCAPED BY '\"';
> ```

What am I doing incorrectly? Any guidance or example is appreciated - thanks!

**Edit:**

- I'm running my console from Google Cloud Shell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When running the Google Cloud Console, local files can be accessed thru the "Launch Code Editor" in the top right. There you will see a file explorer to which you can upload files.

This will be your "local" directory from where the `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE` pulls from.

Answer (score 1):

In windows the folder seperator is `\` so correct format should be

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE "C:\\Users\\user1\gcp\\Feb_Pull.csv" ...
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Caner. \ creates a line break when I execute the command. I've also tried using \\ which removes the line break but no luck. I am running the console from GCP - Google Cloud Shell.

Comment: @Nelson right, it should be `\\` So what error/problem do you have with that?

Comment: I realized my problem - I misinterpreted what `LOCAL` meant - it should not be on my local drive on my computer, but rather the local drive from which the console is running